# Complex serial and parallel promises resolution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

So I have this function that does 4 things, which have to be sequenced the following way:

```
- promise1
- promiseAfter1
// In parallel
- promise2
- promiseAfter2
```

To get the serial promises I shall write:

```
async sequence1() {
  const result = await promise1();
  const finalResult = await promiseAfter1(result);
}
async sequence2() {
  const result = await promise2();
  const finalResult = await promiseAfter2(result);
}
```

And then:

```
async finalSequence() {
  await Promise.all([sequence1, sequence2]);
}
```

But in order to achieve this, I had to create two sub-functions (`sequence1` and `sequence2`) which I'd like to avoid for code readability among other reasons.

Is there a way to achieve the same result without having to create two sub-functions?

Shouldn't there be something like `Promise.sequence` that would sequentially resolve promises?

This would write:

```
Promise.all([
  Promise.sequence([promise1, promiseAfter1]),
  Promise.sequence([promise2, promiseAfter2]),
])
```

Cheers

Comment: There isn't: you probably have to roll your own :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But in order to achieve this, I had to create two sub-functions (`sequence1` and `sequence2`) which I'd like to avoid for code readability among other reasons.

I'd say it's *more* readable with those functions, rather than less, provided you give them meaningful names. But it's a matter of opinion.

> Shouldn't there be something like `Promise.sequence` that would sequentially resolve promises?

Not really, no; it doesn't fit with the other promise combinators (`Promise.all`, etc.). The thing about the promise combinators is that they work with *promises*, but your `Promise.sequence` would need to work with *functions* instead. Remember that `Promise.all`, etc., don't make anything happen that wouldn't already have happened, they just observe and combine the results of things completing. That's what promises are for: Observing the results of asynchronous processes.

There is something built-in for doing things in sequence, though, something that takes functions: `then`

```
async finalSequence() {
    await Promise.all([
        promise1().then(promiseAfter1),
        promise2().then(promiseAfter2),
    ]);
}
```

Or if you don't want to pass the results from one to the next, you could use inline functions:

```
// Either
async finalSequence() {
    await Promise.all([
        promise1().then(() => promiseAfter1()),
        promise2().then(() => promiseAfter2()),
    ]);
}
// Or
async finalSequence() {
    await Promise.all([
        (async () => { await promise1(); await promiseAfter1(); })(),
        (async () => { await promise2(); await promiseAfter2(); })(),
    ]);
}
```

*(Those differ slightly in terms of what ends up in the array from `Promise.all`, but you're not using that array, so...)*

But if you wanted to write `sequence` (say, assuming the functions should be called without arguments) to put in your standard utility library (we all have one, right? :-) ), it's straightforward to do:

```
async function sequence(functions) {
    for (const fn of functions) {
        await fn();
    }
}
```

Then as you say, `finalSequence` would be:

```
async finalSequence() {
    await Promise.all([
        sequence(promise1, promiseAfter1),
        sequence(promise2, promiseAfter2),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Great complete answer! I went for the `then` version which I like quite. I see the difference between function and promise but this is ambiguous as `then` does expect a function that returns a promise. So I guess it *could* make sense with a name like `Promise.thenEach`, couldn't it? :-D

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger - :-) Perhaps!